# Identifying Symmetric Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary $nxn$ matrices, which of the matrices must be symmetric?

$something^T$ means the transpose of "something".

1. $A^T$$A$
2. $A-A^T$
3. $A^TB^TBA$

Comment: A matrix $C$ is symmetric if $C=C^T$. Can you use this way to show that some of these matrices are symmetric?

Comment: 1 is symmetric, 2 is skew-symmetric, 3 is symmetric

Comment: @Element118 should I check whether $(A^TA)^T$=$A^TA$ to check whether number one is symmetric?